# Git - branches on forks

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to set up a correct way of forking/branching for my team during development.

We work an a repo that is not ours, so each team member created a new fork for himself.
The idea is that everyone creates a new branch on his fork for every new task that we do. Once finished and tested, that branch should be merged to his fork, and then a pull request should be made to be merged to the master repo. In the meantime, while task is in testing, developer works on the next task.

**For example:**

- dev1 will be working on tasks 1 and 2, and dev2 will be working on tasks 3 and 4
- dev1 syncs his fork with latest changes from upstream repo and creates a new branch on his fork, names it task1_branch
- dev2 does the same and names his branch task3_branch
- dev1 finishes his task1 and delivers it to QA department for testing, and starts working on task2
- dev2 does the same with task3, and starts with task4
- QA approves task1
- dev1 checks out to task1_branch, merges it with his fork and creates a pull request for the master repo

**Question 1:**
Is this a correct way to use git for such stuff?

**Question 2:**
Is this the right workflow for the above (step 6 needs correcting):

1. git checkout master - checkout to fork master, if not already there
2. git fetch upstream - fetch the branches and their respective commits from the upstream repository
3. git merge upstream/master - merge the changes from upstream/master into the local master branch
4. git push - to update your fork with latest changes from upstream
5. create a new branch under your fork with the task name (e.g. task1_branch) - you can do this on git website under your fork
6. git fetch origin - to pull your newly created branch
7. git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name (checkout to the newly created branch from step 5)
8. commit changes to that branch once you finish development
9. do steps 1-4
10. git checkout branch_name
11. git merge master (to apply latest changes from upstream)
12. git push -u origin branch_name